# automatic button sorting based on value

Tags: vb.net

I've made a program that while running will create buttons and place them in a FlowLayoutPanel, With each click of the different buttons changes the values of the buttons.  With each click I want the list of buttons to be sorted from highest to lowest .tag value.

I'm not sure if you would try to move all the buttons or re value and name each of the buttons.  and this has to effect all the buttons that are created with in the run-time.

Any and all help would be great thank you

I'm using vb2008

Comment: Maybe you could use a `Sortedlist` somehow for the buttons ?

Comment: Well i also figured that i"m going to have to out put all the information the program creates like the 50+ buttons and the values .text and . tag information it has and the buttons commands that were all created in the run time so when the program closes all the information and button locations are saved.  I'm trying to figure all that out too. it's been a long time since i did any programming. so i'm defently needing some help.

Comment: I wounder if i can just program the moving of just 1 button to the bottom of the list if all the other buttons will move up automatically because im using the FlowLayoutPanel. when it creates a button it automatically put it in the list just below the last one that was created.

Comment: well im still having no luck moving the buttons anyone else know how i might go about doing this?